# How to get the current route with Pyramid

Tags: python, routes, pyramid

How can I get the current route of the page that's being shown?

Better yet - would be getting the current view class added with config.add_view.

I need that information to highlight the current item in the menu

```
<li class="'active' if path=='foo' else ''">
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `request.matched_route`. Not sure which templating engine you are using, but something like:

```
<li class="{% if request.matched_route.name == 'foo' %}active{% endif %}">
```

You can also do `request.matched_route.path`. More information can be found here: [The Matched Route](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/narr/urldispatch.html#matched-route)

Comment: btw, that syntax is for the Jinja2 templating engine

Answer (score 1):

I've handled this same situation like this:

```
<li ${'class="active"' if request.url == request.route_url('clientemails', clientid=request.session['selectedclientid']) else '' | n}>
                                <a href="${request.route_url('clientemails', clientid=request.session['selectedclientid'])}">Email
                                    Addresses</a>
                            </li>
```

Comment: This would work but it's too long and prone to errors. It's difficult to remember to add a new route to this place when there are many pages and routes in a larger project.

Comment: I like this coz it is better at handling complex traversal urls (i.e. long, nested contexts) that `matched_route` could never see.